# Dividing process on batches

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron, newsletter

I have newsletter service where users could receive emails for news daily.

I get all the users email from the DB(MYSQL) with PHP, Then I send the emails for all of them with one script.

```
$query = 'SELECT email FROM users';
```

Now the users are increased and I had issues with execution time limit, The hosting provider increased it, But that's not enough.

So I want to divide this process on batches, Like sending 100-200 emails each 10 minutes for example.

```
$query = 'SELECT email FROM users LIMIT 100';
```

By saving the last id in a table and the next time I get it and start from the next id.

```
$lastId = "SELECT id FROM last_id"; //Id from previous time script was executed (100, 200 300, ..etc)
$query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id>$lastId LIMIT 100";
```

But at some point, All the users would receive the emails and the file would be executed for nothing.

So is it possible to stop executing that cron job, After all the users receive the emails?

Comment: I would suggest that use a queuing system instead, eg: [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). Put all the users list into the queue at once. Then let consumers do the work in a repetitive fashion as long as data is there in the queue. You can define consumers to spawn every minute or so. If there is nothing in the queue, they will simply close down, with minimal overhead.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I haven't used such service before, Is it free or premium? Are there are any requirements for it to work on my server?

Comment: Free / opensource. No special requirements. Just go through the link I shared, there are enough tutorials there to get you started